# ServiceStack Operation are not showing in metadata when using with Repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

This is the DTO

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeeAddress { get; set; }

    }
```

This is the Response

```
 public class EmployeeResponse
    {
        public List<Employee> listofemp { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the Service stack Service

```
public class EmployeeServices:Service
    {
        public dbRepo<Employee> objEmploye; //Repository (which is working fine)

        public EmployeeServices()
        {
            objEmploye = new dbRepo<Employee>();
        }


      public object getAll(Employee obj)
      {
          var objlist = new EmployeeResponse {listofemp = objEmploye.GetAll().ToList()};
          return objlist.listofemp;
      }

    }
```

this is the AppHostBase class

```
public class ServiceHostApp:AppHostBase
    {
        public ServiceHostApp()
            : base("ServiceStack WebSerivces", typeof(EmployeeServices).Assembly)
        {
        }
        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {


        }
    }
```

[image: Service Stack Operations are not showoing]

My Question is why EmployeeServices Metod are not showing in the Metadata ? 
is there any additional thing do i need to do ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ServiceStack operates on the method names matching the Http Verb used, so instead of `getAll` you should really be using `Get` (or `All` if any verb can be used to do that).

No need to return an `object`...

```
  public List<Employee> Get(Employee obj)
  {
      var objlist = new EmployeeResponse {listofemp = objEmploye.GetAll().ToList()};
      return objlist.listofemp;
  }
```

Lastly, you can always adorn `Employee` with:

```
[Route("/Employee")]
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeeAddress { get; set; }

}
```

That attribute is define in the namespace `ServiceStack.ServiceHost`.

Comment: Thanks.. It's working now :) ServiceStack methods are Verb Based :) thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to have configured any routes and also haven't respected the naming convention of the service operation.

So you should decorate your request DTO with the Route attribute:

```
[Route("/employees")]
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

and have your service operation be named with the HTTP verb you want it to be accessible with (GET in your case):

```
public object Get(Employee obj)
{
    var objlist = new EmployeeResponse {listofemp = objEmploye.GetAll().ToList()};
    return objlist.listofemp;
}
```

Now when you navigate to `GET /employees` the Get operation will be executed.

Bear in mind that you can also configure your routes using the [`Fluent API`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#fluent-api) instead of using the Route attribute:

```
Routes.Add<Employee>("/employees", "GET");
```

Comment: Thanks for Your help, working now :) +1'd to your answer and giving Fluent Api Option :)